# iPhone sdk how to set view orientation with two different views displayed by segmented control

Tags: iphone, sdk, view, orientation

I'm using a segmented control that has two segments.

- When segment 1 is pressed, I display a view that contains a tableview of which I don't want landscape orientation, only portrait.
- When segment 2 is pressed, I display a different view of which I want to allow landscape orientation.

So, I'm using the following code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   if (self.view == self.myFirstView)
      return false;
   else if (self.view == self.mySecondView)
      return true;
}
```

This all works nicely, except for the following condition:  If the user selects segment 2, and then rotates the phone, the view goes into landscape mode.  Then, while still holding the phone in landscape mode, the user presses segment 1.  This displays the first view in landscape mode (I only want this view to be displayed in portrait mode).

So, the question is, how do I show the first view, but reset the view orientation to portrait?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to use device orientation to set portrait/landscape as well as your segmented control?

Seems like you're providing multiple means of setting orientation which would confuse the user, and maybe, it seems, you too ;-)

Comment: I'm not providing multiple means of setting orientation.  I'm simply allowing 1 view to display in landscape and portrait mode, and 1 view to display in portrait mode only.  Seems like a simple concept to me.

Comment: I think you may be confused as to what I'm doing.  My segmented control is not display any particular orientation.  My segmented control displays 1 of 2 views based on which segment was clicked.  View 1 doesn't support landscape, but View 2 does (they both support portrait)  I'm not manually changing the orientation, so the shouldn't be confused by anything.  The catch is.. when the user chooses View 2 and tilts the phone to go into landscape mode, then choose View 1, my View 1 is displayed in landscape mode (which I don't want).

Answer (score 0):

in view1, get the orientation, and if it is landscape switch it to portratit.